# На php сервер приходит POST запрос, как его обработать чтоб быть в безопасности?

Tags: php, безопасность

Хотелось бы узнать минимальный, оптимальный набор защиты и максимальный если можно:)

Обезопасить от всего. Из баз данных MongoDB, Redis.

Comment: Защиты чего от чего? Данные POST - набор байт и ничего более, как его сами обработаете - такая безопасность и будет. Нужна конкретика.

Comment: "Обезопасить от всего" - это книга в несколько сотен страниц получится, нужна конкретика.

Answer (score 6):

Никак.
Ответ на этот вопрос невозможен в принципе.
А любой ответ, который будет дан, будет заведомо неверным.

Данные сами по себе безопасны. Небезопасен программист, который не знает, как с ними обращаться.
К примеру, SQL инъекций не существует. Есть только программисты, которые не умеют составлять SQL запросы.
Грамотно составленный запрос полностью неуязвим для любых инъекций.
Неграмотно составленный запрос будет вызывать ошибки и ломать сайт даже без всякого хакера, на соверешнно невинных данных.

То же самое касается и остальных "баз данных MongoDB, Redis."
Надо обрабатывать не "входящие данные", а исходящие, соответственно с правилами принимающей стороны. Для каждой конкретно.

Именно поэтому программисту надо не колупаться с низкоуровневыми функциями типа муэскуэль_фетч_аррей(), а пользоваться высокоуровневыми инструментами, которые написаны профессионалами, и умеют форматировать данные за программиста.

- для работы с SQL базами надо использовать ORM
- для вывода данных надо использовать шаблонизатор с автоискейпингом

и так далее.

Входящая же обработка будет только портить данные.
В РНР раньше была такая настройка, magic_quotes. Как раз такая вот попытка "обезопасить сразу на входе". Как потом выяснилось, безопасности она не прибавляла, а вот головной боли от нее было много, и её наконец-то убрали.

Comment: "Небезопасен программист, который не знает, как с ними обращаться." - отличная фраза, надо запомнить

Answer (score 0):

Обезопасить от чего?? от XSS или SQLInj???
mysql_real_escape_string(); - данные к БД можно пропускать через эту функцию.
htmlspecialchars(); - не много поможет от XSS.
Так-же можно делать полную проверку полей на вводимость данных!

Comment: Только не можно, а нужно.

Comment: @LevBazdyrev, перед тем как написать ответ, вы вопрос читали?

Comment: Я немного поправил вопрос после этого ответа)